# Is it possible to lock the view while building?

Tags: dragon-quest-builders

In the game when holding ZL or ZR to build or destroy above or under it locks the camera and allows you to strafe. Which is useful in some situation. I however didn't find a button that allows you to lock the camera and strafe while "aiming" at ground level as opposed to above or under. **Is there such a command in the game ?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To lock the view and strafe at ground level you need to hold the button Z & L (or ZR & ZL), this way you character will not place a stack of two of the material you have when keeping the button Y pressed.